# how to set work-week as the initial format in a Domino calendar view?

Tags: lotus-domino

I want my Domino Calendar View to be initially setup in work-week format (showing monday to friday days)

In Designer, I go to `View Properties` - `Date and Time Format` tab. There is a `Initial Format` combo box where I can choose from those items.

```
- Default - 
One Day
Two Days
Work Calendars
One Week
Two Weeks
One Month
```

But none of them gives me the desired work-week format.

Interestingly, it is available to the users thru the Week Tab in the View Header.

I am wondering if there is any way to select it programmatically.

What is the formula to change the calendar format? 
when is (what is the event) appropiate to execute it?

This is Domino 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've given up.

I have selected `Default` as the `Initial Format` in the `View Properties - Date and Time Format` tab.

So, the user can choose whatever she wants and Notes will remember the chosen format for her.

Answer (score 1):

You can add code to the PostOpen event of your view to change the calendar format. In formula language, you can use this:

```
@Command( [CalendarFormat] ; "5" )
```

The "5" represents a Work Week view.

Comment: it does not work for me. I have put this formula in the PostOpen event, I've tried QueryOpen too. I have changed the Initial Format in View Properties - Date and Time Format to different values. It seems as if the formula never gets executed or if the Initial Format chosen overrides it.